# Dynamically create an HTML document using javascript using window

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a new HTML page using javascript.
To do that I tried using the window object

```
let myDocument = window;

myDocument.document.write(`
     <html>
         <head>
               <title>${title}</title>
         </head>
         <body><section id="print"></section></body>
     </html>
`)
```

My problem is that I would like to generate that on the background and save the result somewhere in my project.

- The user cannot see a new page open or a new window
- The new HTML has to be saved

These are the two problems I have at the moment.
I can generate the page, but I could not find out how to do that on the background.
My limitation is that the project uses pure javascript so Node.js packages might not work.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the goal? Anyhow I would personally use HTML5's offline storage

Comment: There's no need for window object in this? Why not simply store HTML in a variable?

Comment: I need to dynamically add html on it too

Comment: `Document.write` is no longer suitable for anything like this - Chrome, and possibly webkit browsers in general - does not create a new execution context for the page written with `document.write` so JavaScript written into the document risks generating  errors because you've used the same variable name previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.write` you can save it in a variable & use it when you want or save it through `service` or `localStorage`.

You code must be like:

```js
const title = "Hello World!";
let myDocument =
     `<html>
         <head>
               <title>${title}</title>
         </head>
         <body><section id="print"></section></body>
     </html>`;
     
console.log(myDocument);
```

Comment: That will solve at least three problems... The actual and two I would have in the future.
So simple and I didn't see it, thanks a lot!